# Reset integer daily, in specific time

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.0

I need to reset an integer "daily" at a set specific time of day. In my activity, I write the value of daily into Shared preferences, then with an alarm manager and broadcast receiver try to set it to zero. everything works, besides the shared preferences and the value still remains what it was. I think that I need to import a different context for the shared prefs. Any help is welcomed.

The receiver:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final SharedPreferences shared =  context.getSharedPreferences("Mydata", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
    int sum = shared.getInt("data1", 0);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DATE));

    mainData.insert_data(date, sum);
    int zero = 0;
    editor.putInt("data1", zero);
    editor.apply();

}
```

The alarm manager:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        final Context context = this.getContext();
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MyAppReciever.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

The Shared preferences in the Main Activity:

```
final SharedPreferences shared = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("Mydata", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
        editor.putInt("data1", 0);
        editor.putInt("month", 0);
        final int today212 = shared.getInt("data1", 0);
        final int mesec212 = shared.getInt("month", 0);
        final int limit212 = shared.getInt("budget", 0);
```

Comment: Do you update `SharedPreferences` in `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Yes, and I suspect that that is the problem

Comment: I don't think so. How do you check your `Integer` isn't updated?

Comment: I refresh a text value that gets the shared prefs every time

Comment: Are you sure `onReceive` is called? Do you use `apply()` on `Editor`?

Comment: Yes, and yes  111  1

Comment: I wıll edıt the questıon above wıth some code ın a second

Comment: Looks good. Did you check `/data/data/your_package/shared_pref` to see actual shared pref file values? There are two options: You don't write new value or you read it back wrong (maybe you references old value)

Comment: I wıll Update the Shared preferences that I have set In my activity.

Comment: Still, the code about reading preferences in `MainActivity` might be called only once or before an actual update will happen.

Comment: I tried doing it on click and it still does not work

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a few changes to the code and added a PendingIntent requestCode.
The code looks like this

The place where you set up your Alarm:

```
public void scheduleTestAlarmReceiver(Context context) {
    Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(context, MyAppReciever.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123456789, receiverIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
}
```

and the place where you schedule it (say onClick):

```
Context cn= this.getContext();
        scheduleTestAlarmReceiver(cn);
```

the Broadcast receiver should be the same as above.
And also do not forget to add the receiver to the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyAppReciever"></receiver>
```